# Prove that $M$ is normal surface

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification

Let  $M$ be the  set $\{(x,y,z)\in  \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus(0,0,0):z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\}$, prove  that $M$ is an embedded 2-d submanifold or a normal surface.

---

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3  \to   \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y,z)=z^2-x^2-y^2$

$f $ is $C^{\infty}$  and the Jacobian   is $Df=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
-2x & -2y & 2z 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ which has rank  $1$ since $(0,0,0)\notin M$

So $M=f^{-1}(0)$ is a  $(3-1)=2$ dimentional submanifold or a normal surface.

---

**Is this  correct ?**

Comment: Yes, it's correct. But you also need to find a point of the manifold for the inverse image it's not trivial. For example the point $(1,0,1)\in M$

Comment: What is a “normal surface”?

Comment: @TedShifrin an embedded 2-d submanifold

Comment: I guess some texts refer to this as a *regular* surface. Perhaps this is a language issue.